# (DNN/2sxc) Tokens in Template doesn't replaced with values

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a problem with an token template in 2sxc V.8.4.5 on DNN 7.4.2. It's a template with support ListContent and ListPresentation:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">[ListContent:Toolbar]
    <h[ListContent:Presentation:TitleHTag] style="text-align:[ListContent:Presentation:TitleTextAlign];">[ListContent:Titel]</h[ListContent:Presentation:TitleHTag]>
    <p style="text-align:[ListContent:Presentation:TextTextAlign];">[ListContent:Text]</p>

<repeat>
    <div class="col-md-[Content:Presentation:BootstrapWidthContent]">[Content:Toolbar]
        <div>
            <p><img src="[Content:Image]" style="float:[Content:Presentation:CssImageFloat];margin-top:8px; width:[Content:Presentation:CssWidthImage]"/></p>
        </div>
       <h[Content:Presentation:Title1HTag] class="[Content:Presentation:CssClassColorTitle]">[Content:Title]</h[Content:Presentation:Title1HTag]>
        <h[Content:Presentation:Title2HTag] class="[Content:Presentation:CssClassColorTitle2]">[Content:SubTitle]</h[Content:Presentation:Title2HTag]>
         <div class="[Content:Presentation:CssClassColorText]">[Content:Text]<br /><br />
            <a class="[Content:Presentation:CssClassColorLinkText]" href="[Content:Link]">[Content:LinkText]</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</repeat>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem are at the lines:

```
<h[Content:Presentation:Title1HTag] class="[Content:Presentation:CssClassColorTitle]">[Content:Title]</h[Content:Presentation:Title1HTag]>
<h[Content:Presentation:Title2HTag] class="[Content:Presentation:CssClassColorTitle2]">[Content:SubTitle]</h[Content:Presentation:Title2HTag]>
```

Some tokens in that lines are not replaced with values. i'm getting

```
<h class="titlered">Title1<h>
<h class="titlered">Title2<h>
```

It cannot be a problem with Content:Presentation, because the other tokens from this presentation are correct replaced.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess a bit, but I'm thinking of some kind of spelling / naming issues. Are you sure, that the field is really called Title1HTag, or could it be a misspelling like Titel1HTag or TitleH1Tag?

I recommend that you try to output the value somewhere else just to look at it, like

```
XXX[tag-to-test]YYY
```

Comment: i've changed the name, but same result...and the output as text looks like XXXYYY...

Comment: Could you add screenshots of the content-type definition for the presentation item (because I think there is a naming issue of the field name) + the latest source-code you're using?

Comment: i've updated to V.8.4.6 with the same result. 
Here are the screenshots 
![Content Presentation](http://www.indisoftware.de/Portals/0/img/contentpresentation.jpg) 
![Title1HTag](http://www.indisoftware.de/Portals/0/img/title1HTag.jpg)

Comment: Your pics look ok. could you add a screenshot of the presentation-entities table - just to see what number is actually stored in the value when looking at the table-view in the data admin

Comment: i've changed the template from Token to Razor and now everything is fine...